# MVC Redirect ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

On a MVC controller I have the following:

```
public virtual ActionResult Test() {
  ActionResult result = MVC.Home.Index();
  return RedirectToAction(result);
  return View();
}
```

This redirects to result. View is never returned.

Now I need to do something as follows:

```
public virtual ActionResult Test() {
  ActionResult result = MVC.Home.Index();
  MyClass.RedirectTo(result, this);
  return View();
}
```

Where MyClass.RedirectTo method is the following:

```
public static void RedirectTo(ActionResult result, Controller controller) {
  controller.Response.Redirect(result.ToString());            
}
```

But in this case the redirection does not happen.

The View is returned. Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I have 3 questions: 1)why do you use virtual methods in a controller??
2) How in heaven's name do you write 2 return statements in 1 method?
3) could you explain in plain text what it is you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to take your user to?

Comment: Hello. I do use virtual in my controllers. But after trying this I think what I am trying to do is impossible. I am trying to find another way ... Basically on my controllers I get a DTO Response. The response wraps DTO models and info on Exceptions. Basically I am trying to create a Fluent Validation for those Responses which would fire a RedirectToAction on error ... But I understand now the way I am going is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to redirect to a specific action on a specific controller

e.g 
return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName");